# How to include qrc data into Qt-based binary that was compiled using CMake

Tags: c++, qt, binary, cmake, qt5

I have a big Qt + third-party-library project which I try to compile into a binary so that to test the program in another machine. I was able to make the binary run (found all the necessary `*.dll`s and plugins), however, I cannot figure out how to include a `*.qrc` data with icons for my program. For the moment, the binary cannot load any icons, so I have just buttons with text.

The code structure of my program is as follows:

- **root_folder**

  - `CMakeLists.txt`
  - **program_folder**

    - `main.cpp`
    - `CMakeLists.txt`
    - **data_folder** / `Data.qrc` and set of icons in `svg` format
    - other `.cpp` and `.h` files
  - **lib_folder1**
  - **lib_folder2**
  - ...

This is how `Data.qrc` file looks inside:

```
RCC>
<qresource prefix="/">
    <file>file-name.svg</file>
    ...
```

This is how I add the resources to my program, inside the `CMakeLists.txt` of the **program_folder**:

```
qt5_add_resources(IMG_RSC_ADDED data_folder/Data.qrc )
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_SRCS} ${IMG_RSC_ADDED} )
```

Inside one of the `.cpp` files of **program_folder** I load the icons:

```
static QIcon icon(QPixmap(":/file-name.svg"));
```

For the icons,  I have a `class Data{};` and inside that class I have a set of methods, e.g., `static const QIcon& fileIcon();`. And in the main code, when I need to use the icon, I call it this way: `Data::fileIcon()`.

It works when I compile and run from the source.

I prepared the binary distribution of my program, and this it how it is structured inside some root folder:

- **imageformats**

  - `qsvg.dll`
- **platforms**

  - `qwindows.dll`
- `my_program.exe`
- `Qt5Core.dll`
- other Qt and 3rd-party-lib `dll`s

My question is how and where do I put the data files? I tried different locations, e.g., inside the main folder, inside created `Data` folder. And I simply copied all the data I had (`svg` file, `qrc` file), but the binary still cannot see the resources. How to solve it? Or, what is the common practice?

Note, I am using CMake (not QMake) to compile my binary. I am using Qt-5.4, on Windows 7. Let me know if my question lacks details, I will add them. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your problem, qrc resources are embedded in the binary by default. What data files you are talking about?

Comment: If they are embedded, then why binary cannot find them? By data files I mean svg files, since that's how they are referred to in my code, e.g., `QPixmap(":/file-name.svg")`.

Comment: That's a different matter which should be investigated but `qt5_add_resources` line does the following: it generates binary data of all the resources from the provided qrc files and output this data to the fiels the list of which is stored in your `IMG_RSC_ADDED`. You can check what it contains by priniting it with the message command: `message(${IMG_RSC_ADDED})`

Comment: The thing I don't like in your code is **static** QIcon. Do you have them as such in the function or global scope?

Comment: Interesting. I will look what the resources contain as you advised. For the `static`, I have a `class Data{};` and inside that class I have a set of methods, e.g.,  `static const QIcon& fileIcon();`. And in the main code, when I need to use the icon, I call it this way: `Data::fileIcon()`. Why it might not be good to use `static`?

Comment: static members initialization order is not defined but it's guaranteed to complete before main starts and you are using QPixmap which requires QApplication created and running. So first of all before any further investigation try to put the initialization of at least a couple of your QIcons in the class constructor. So you will have your QIcon like this: `static QIcon icon; ` and in the ctor you will initialize it: `icon = QIcon(QPixmap(":/file-name.svg"));` and see it it helps

Comment: It looks like this is the right direction, and the problem is how my `Data` class organized and how I load the icons (I put initialization in ctor and the icon is now part of binary as you commented above). If you could summarize the last statement in an answer, I will accept it. It looks like my question was ill-formulated and did not reflect the actual problem. Thank you for helping to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command `qt5_add_resources(IMG_RSC_ADDED data_folder/Data.qrc)` makes source files with binary data generate from each resource from the provied qrc files(Data.qrc in this case) and the list of the resulting files is stored in the `IMG_RSC_ADDED` variable. Provided this variable is passed to `add_executable` all the resources get embedded in the resulting binary.

Next, to the actual problem: the problem is not with the distribution but with the code itself. You create and initialize `QIcon`s in the static context and use `QPixmap` for it but `QPixmap` requires `QApplication` up and running which is not the case with the static initialization context. So the proper fix is to move the initialization of the `QIcon`s to some local context(like class ctor or the main function)